# kg, km/h, meters box2d

Tags: performance, box2d

I don't really get it:
I would like to construct a body which is
10 Meters long,
5000kg heavy
and drives 10km/h fast.

What ist this in the box2d world in 
pixels,
mass
f
?

Answer (score 1):

Box2D doesn't work with pixels, but it has been engineered to work with human scale objects. From the [manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082967)

> Box2D works with floating point
>   numbers, so some tolerances have to be
>   used to make Box2D perform well. These
>   tolerances have been tuned to work
>   well with meters-kilogram-second (MKS)
>   units. In particular, Box2D has been
>   tuned to work well with moving objects
>   between 0.1 and 10 meters. So this
>   means objects between soup cans and
>   buses in size should work well. Static
>   objects may be up to 50 meters without
>   too much trouble.

So, think about the relative sizes of other objects in your game, and try to ensure they sit with the 0.1 -> 10 range (i.e. 2 orders of magnitude). Then scale them appropriately in the engine. You'll have another units->pixels scale factor for rendering the output of the engine.

Answer (score 0):

How many pixels in a metre?

I don't know, it depends on your game. 1 pixel = 20cm might be fine for a tanks game, but is ludicrously inappropriate for anything set in space. My advice would be to *forget metres entirely*. It doesn't matter what the absolute value of anything is - what matters is *how big that is in comparison to everything else*.

Over the course of an hour, your body will move 1000 times its own length. Pick a number of pixels that *looks good* in game, and base everything else off that.